# Does Chile have a government owned Export Import bank like the US or India?

Tags: finance, international-trade, credit

If not, what type of trade financing do Chilean exporters or importers get? Is it all from private banks and insurers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chile joined the OECD in 2010 but does not have an official export credit agency listed by the OECD in its involved in the [Export Credit Group](http://www.oecd.org/tad/xcred/eca.htm)

The Inter-American Development Bank is [lending US$27 million](https://www.iadb.org/en/news/news-releases/2017-11-09/chile-to-boost-global-export-services%2C11947.html) to the Chilean Finance Ministry to support export promotion and services, but this does not look like financing

So I would assume that financing comes from private sources (in particular Chile has large private pension systems) and foreign export credit agencies, plus the usual market operations of the Chilean central bank to ensure monetary stability and liquidity in the context of a floating exchange rate significantly affected by the world price of copper